# Need help running a sed command on my production server

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, sed, terminal

I am  trying to do a simple find a replace using using sed. The  command below works perfectly fine on my local unix machine on my mac. However on my production server which is using centos6, is giving me the following error message.....

```
sed: can't read s/!BGCOLOR!/#3a1504/: No such file or directory
```

Below is the command I am trying to use

```
 sed -n 73p  style.css | cut -c  29-35 | xargs -I  :hex: sed -i '' 's/!BGCOLOR!/:hex:/'  custom.css
```

any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Please consider giving your question a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 0):

The empty argument to `-i` is superfluous.

The *BSD dialect of `sed` requires this argument, but on Linux, it is not used, and so your CentOS `sed` thinks that `''` is your script and the next argument is the name of the file to run it on.

Comment: Thanks for the response...so do i just remove the '' and -i all together?

Comment: Keep just the `-i` if you want it.